# How do you insert a column using the column editor in sharepoint designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calculated-column

I would like to create a new calculated column in Sharepoint Designer 2010. So, IN SPD 2010 / Site columns, I click New, Calculated column, fill in the details and click OK. Up comes the the Column Editor dialog box.

On the right there is a long vertical field, titled 'Insert Column' with nothing in it. Below this field there is an 'Add to formula' button.  On the left there is a Formula field in which I can directly type my formula, and another field in which I can control the Data type returned.

My question is this:  How do you use the field on the right to insert a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in SharePoint Designer 2010 RTM. You can still create site level calculated columns using this dialog, but will have to reference the column names yourself. For example:

> = [Principal] * [Interest Rate]

Calculated columns created in lists work as expected.